# How to make <td> clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have created a table to display my SPARQL query result in the `<td>`, the result does display however I want it that when the`<td>` (result) is clicked on it displays a message box. Right now an extra `<td>` is displayed at the top and it only works for that particular one. Nothing seems to happen when clicking on the actual result `<td>`:

My code:

```
    <table id="results">
    <td class="td" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
    </table>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?country_name
WHERE {
    ?country rdf:type type:Country108544813.
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_name.

}
                "Limit 1"
                ].join(" ");

                alert("this query: [" + query + "]");

                var queryUrl = url + "?query=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&format=json";




</body>
```

The JavaScript code I got it from an online material so still getting my head around it , the main use of it is to display the query result. So yeah answers are really appreciated and thanks for reading:)

Comment: you could add a click event to the td you want to be active

Comment: can you post the rendered html that is returned from your ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, your html is a little off... Your table is outside the  tag, when it should be inside it: (note a td usually would be in a  too)

```
<body>
    <table id="results">
        <tr><td class="td" onclick="myFunction()"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ....
```

But to your question more precisely: you have created *one* cell, and attached an onclick event handler to it and it only. The javascript code you grabbed actually *appends* new rows and cells to the table, and those don't have onclick handlers assigned.

So I'd try something like this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var table = $("#results");
        table.on("click", "td", myFunction); // <-- magic!
        var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
```

The "magic" line is the sweet part: it attaches the handler on the *whole* table, but filter the events by the "td" selector. Ideal when you are adding DOM elements dynamically...

And then you don't need to set your initial td, then one that is empty at the top of your table and clickable... Instead, just place an empty table on your page:

```
<body>
    <table id="results"></table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ....
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

While looking over your code you seam to only have the click event on the static

```
<table id="results">
<td class="td" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
</table>
```

When you add the dynamical  the is no class or onclick event.  You can fix this by either adding the onclick to the td dynamically or running a script that sets all the tds in that table to have the same click event.

```
function getTableCell(fieldName, rowData) {
            //var td = $("<td></td>");
              var td = $("<td class="td" onclick="myFunction()"></td>");
            var fieldData = rowData[fieldName];
            //alert("fieldName = ["+fieldName +"] rowData[fieldName][value] = ["+rowData[fieldName]["value"] + "]");
            td.html(fieldData["value"]);
            return td;
        }
```

or

```
$("#results td").click(function(){
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just delegate the click event handler from a static element, like `#results`? Then, even if you add dynamic elements, you don't have to re-add bindings each time. I would think `$("#results").on("click", "td", function() { do some code });` would do it, yeah?

Comment: You could but that was not the question asked.  He wanted to be able to click on any td element in the table.  If he wanted to click on any td element at all you could you use:

Comment: Gotcha, yeah - I updated my comment, thanks for the catch!

Comment: $("td"), sorry it wouldn't let me edit my other comment

Comment: What you are asking is the second part of my answer.  I am just using the click event instead of the on event.